# Typescript causing syntax error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typescript

I am new to `typescript` and am trying to get a simple class going.  I have the below code and when I run, I keep getting a syntax error.  I tried even an empty class and nothing.

I am using `ASP.NET MVC5` (note, if I just have a function in the code, it works fine).

Inside Site.ts I have:

```
class Facebook {
    constructor() { }

    open() {
        window.open("http://www.facebook.com");
    }
}

var social = new Facebook();
```

I am calling the code by a link

```
<a href="javascript:social.open()">open</a>
```

I don't even get to click, right away, when loading I get

```
JavaScript critical error at line 1, column 1 in http://localhost:20870/Scripts/site.ts\n\nSCRIPT1002: Syntax error
```

It seems to work in the playground:
[Click here to see my workout](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Facebook%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20open()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20window.open(%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20social%20%3D%20new%20Facebook()%3B%0A%0Avar%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20%22Say%20Hello%22%3B%0Abutton.onclick%20%3D%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20social.open()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B%0A)

Any ideas?

Comment: This might be stupid, but did you remember to compile the TypeScript file to JavaScript before including it?

Comment: I checked the csproj and I see <TypeScriptCompile Include="Scripts\site.ts" /> along with the appropriate targets.  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Wow I feel dumb.  I enabled auto-build, but then I realized a browser doesn't know .ts, it only knows .js.  Looked at my bundles and realized I had added site.ts not site.js.  Can you move that to a reply so I can give you answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the browser is trying to execute the TypeScript and not the JavaScript. Double check your `<script>` tags (or any other thing you are using to load the code e.g. requirejs)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, when using a TypeScript tutorial on www.typescriptlang.org.

I realized that my script tag was referencing the TypeScript file and not the JS file:

```
    <script src="greeter.ts"></script>
```

instead of:

```
    <script src="greeter.js"></script>
```